# Elasticsearch aggregation based on nested terms

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have es documents as below

```
{
        "_index" : "candidate",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "oNJLMHsBMf41SmWAkvYj",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "created_at" : "2021-07-15",
          "updated_at" : "2021-08-05T22:33:30.923914+00:00",
          "user_id" : 74780,
          "user_name" : "Steven-c96b54",
          "first_name" : "Steven",
          "last_name" : "Lu",
          "email" : "stevenlu5a@mougulan.com",
          "contact_number" : "",
          "country_code" : "cn",
          "country" : "China",
          "city" : "Shanghai",
          "state" : "Shanghai",
          "address" : "Shanghai, Shanghai, China",
          "active_step" : 5,
          "is_active" : true,
          "is_deleted" : false,
          "is_csv_user" : true,
          "is_profile_completed" : true,
          "profile_completion_percentage" : 0.0,
          "gender" : "Female",
          "title_rank" : "Director of Food & Beverage",
          "race_ethnicity" : "I do not wish to provide this information",
          "years_of_experience" : "12-15",
          "current_organizational_level" : "property",
          "base_salary" : 123,
          "bonus" : "",
          "benefits" : [
            {
              "benefit" : ""
            }
          ],
          "badge" : "Rising Mogul",
          "languages" : [
            {
              "language" : "Chinese"
            }
          ],
          "geographies" : [
            {
              "geography" : "China"
            }
          ],
          "current_position" : "Assistant Director of F&B",
          "seeking_position" : [
            {
              "seeking_position" : "Food & Beverage General Manager"
            },
            {
              "seeking_position" : "Director of Food & Beverage"
            },
            {
              "seeking_position" : "General Manager"
            }
          ],
          "current_location" : [
            {
              "city" : "Shanghai",
              "country" : "China",
              "country_code" : "cn",
              "region" : "China"
            }
          ],
          "preferred_location" : [
            {
              "city" : "",
              "country" : "",
              "country_code" : "",
              "region" : ""
            }
          ],
          "compensation_seeking" : [
            {
              "compensation" : 123,
              "city" : "",
              "country" : "",
              "country_code" : "",
              "region" : ""
            }
          ],
          "brand_experience" : [
            {
              "brand" : "Other",
              "company" : "Other"
            },
            {
              "brand" : "Grand Hyatt",
              "company" : "Hyatt Hotel Corporation"
            },
            {
              "brand" : "St Regis",
              "company" : "Marriott"
            },
            {
              "brand" : "Shangri-La",
              "company" : "Other Lifestyle - Luxury"
            }
          ],
          "brand_segment_experience" : [
            {
              "brand_segment" : "Upper-Upscale"
            },
            {
              "brand_segment" : "Luxury"
            }
          ],
          "real_estate_type_experience" : [
            {
              "real_estate" : "Government"
            }
          ],
          "property_type_experience" : [
            {
              "property_type" : "Full-Service Hotel"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "candidate",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "odJLMHsBMf41SmWAkvYj",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "created_at" : "2021-07-15",
          "updated_at" : "2021-08-05T21:32:43.813128+00:00",
          "user_id" : 74779,
          "user_name" : "Steven-8d832e",
          "first_name" : "Steven",
          "last_name" : "Liu",
          "email" : "stevenliu5a@mougulan.com",
          "contact_number" : "",
          "country_code" : "cn",
          "country" : "China",
          "city" : "Shandong",
          "state" : "Shandong",
          "address" : "Qingdao, Shandong, China",
          "active_step" : 5,
          "is_active" : true,
          "is_deleted" : false,
          "is_csv_user" : true,
          "is_profile_completed" : true,
          "profile_completion_percentage" : 0.0,
          "gender" : "Female",
          "title_rank" : "Director of Rooms",
          "race_ethnicity" : "I do not wish to provide this information",
          "years_of_experience" : "9-12",
          "current_organizational_level" : "corporate",
          "base_salary" : 120,
          "bonus" : "",
          "benefits" : [
            {
              "benefit" : ""
            }
          ],
          "badge" : "",
          "languages" : [
            {
              "language" : "Chinese"
            }
          ],
          "geographies" : [
            {
              "geography" : "China"
            }
          ],
          "current_position" : "",
          "seeking_position" : [
            {
              "seeking_position" : "Director of Room Operations"
            },
            {
              "seeking_position" : "General Manager"
            },
            {
              "seeking_position" : "Director of Rooms"
            }
          ],
          "current_location" : [
            {
              "city" : "Shandong",
              "country" : "China",
              "country_code" : "cn",
              "region" : "China"
            }
          ],
          "preferred_location" : [
            {
              "city" : "",
              "country" : "",
              "country_code" : "",
              "region" : ""
            }
          ],
          "compensation_seeking" : [
            {
              "compensation" : 120,
              "city" : "",
              "country" : "",
              "country_code" : "",
              "region" : ""
            }
          ],
          "brand_experience" : [
            {
              "brand" : "Holiday Inn Hotels & Resorts",
              "company" : "InterContinental Hotels Group"
            },
            {
              "brand" : "Pullman",
              "company" : "Accor"
            },
            {
              "brand" : "Other",
              "company" : "Other"
            }
          ],
          "brand_segment_experience" : [
            {
              "brand_segment" : "Midscale"
            },
            {
              "brand_segment" : "Upper-Upscale"
            },
            {
              "brand_segment" : "Upscale"
            }
          ],
          "real_estate_type_experience" : [
            {
              "real_estate" : "Government"
            }
          ],
          "property_type_experience" : [
            {
              "property_type" : "Full-Service Hotel"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "candidate",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "otJLMHsBMf41SmWAkvYj",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "created_at" : "2021-07-15",
          "updated_at" : "2021-08-05T22:33:25.563336+00:00",
          "user_id" : 74778,
          "user_name" : "Steven-706c40",
          "first_name" : "Steven",
          "last_name" : "Liu",
          "email" : "stevenliu47@mougulan.com",
          "contact_number" : "",
          "country_code" : "cn",
          "country" : "China",
          "city" : "Shanghai",
          "state" : "Shanghai",
          "address" : "Shanghai, Shanghai, China",
          "active_step" : 5,
          "is_active" : true,
          "is_deleted" : false,
          "is_csv_user" : true,
          "is_profile_completed" : true,
          "profile_completion_percentage" : 0.0,
          "gender" : "Female",
          "title_rank" : "Director of Sales & Marketing",
          "race_ethnicity" : "I do not wish to provide this information",
          "years_of_experience" : "9-12",
          "current_organizational_level" : "property",
          "base_salary" : 130,
          "bonus" : "",
          "benefits" : [
            {
              "benefit" : ""
            }
          ],
          "badge" : "Rising Mogul",
          "languages" : [
            {
              "language" : "English"
            }
          ],
          "geographies" : [
            {
              "geography" : "China"
            }
          ],
          "current_position" : "Account Director - MICE & Leisure",
          "seeking_position" : [
            {
              "seeking_position" : "Director of Sales & Marketing"
            },
            {
              "seeking_position" : "Regional Director of Sales"
            },
            {
              "seeking_position" : "Director of Sales Strategy & Planning"
            }
          ],
          "current_location" : [
            {
              "city" : "Shanghai",
              "country" : "China",
              "country_code" : "cn",
              "region" : "China"
            }
          ],
          "preferred_location" : [
            {
              "city" : "",
              "country" : "",
              "country_code" : "",
              "region" : ""
            }
          ],
          "compensation_seeking" : [
            {
              "compensation" : 130,
              "city" : "",
              "country" : "",
              "country_code" : "",
              "region" : ""
            }
          ],
          "brand_experience" : [
            {
              "brand" : "Hilton Hotels & Resorts",
              "company" : "Hilton"
            },
            {
              "brand" : "Westin",
              "company" : "Marriott"
            },
            {
              "brand" : "Swissotel",
              "company" : "Accor"
            }
          ],
          "brand_segment_experience" : [
            {
              "brand_segment" : "Upscale"
            },
            {
              "brand_segment" : "Upper-Upscale"
            }
          ],
          "real_estate_type_experience" : [
            {
              "real_estate" : "Government"
            }
          ],
          "property_type_experience" : [
            {
              "property_type" : "Full-Service Hotel"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "candidate",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "o9JLMHsBMf41SmWAkvYj",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "created_at" : "2021-07-15",
          "updated_at" : "2021-08-05T22:46:07.919661+00:00",
          "user_id" : 74777,
          "user_name" : "Steven-513bc8",
          "first_name" : "Steven",
          "last_name" : "Li",
          "email" : "stevenli77@mougulan.com",
          "contact_number" : "",
          "country_code" : "cn",
          "country" : "China",
          "city" : "Jiangsu",
          "state" : "Jiangsu",
          "address" : "Suzhou, Jiangsu, China",
          "active_step" : 5,
          "is_active" : true,
          "is_deleted" : false,
          "is_csv_user" : true,
          "is_profile_completed" : true,
          "profile_completion_percentage" : 0.0,
          "gender" : "Female",
          "title_rank" : "Director of Rooms",
          "race_ethnicity" : "I do not wish to provide this information",
          "years_of_experience" : "6-9",
          "current_organizational_level" : "property",
          "base_salary" : 140,
          "bonus" : "",
          "benefits" : [
            {
              "benefit" : ""
            }
          ],
          "badge" : "",
          "languages" : [
            {
              "language" : "Chinese"
            }
          ],
          "geographies" : [
            {
              "geography" : "China"
            }
          ],
          "current_position" : "Quality Manager",
          "seeking_position" : [
            {
              "seeking_position" : "Director of Rooms"
            },
            {
              "seeking_position" : "General Manager"
            },
            {
              "seeking_position" : "Director of Room Operations"
            }
          ],
          "current_location" : [
            {
              "city" : "Jiangsu",
              "country" : "China",
              "country_code" : "cn",
              "region" : "China"
            }
          ],
          "preferred_location" : [
            {
              "city" : "",
              "country" : "",
              "country_code" : "",
              "region" : ""
            }
          ],
          "compensation_seeking" : [
            {
              "compensation" : 140,
              "city" : "",
              "country" : "",
              "country_code" : "",
              "region" : ""
            }
          ],
          "brand_experience" : [
            {
              "brand" : "InterContinental Hotels Group",
              "company" : "InterContinental Hotels Group"
            },
            {
              "brand" : "W Hotels",
              "company" : "Marriott"
            }
          ],
          "brand_segment_experience" : [
            {
              "brand_segment" : "Luxury"
            },
            {
              "brand_segment" : "Upper-Upscale"
            },
            {
              "brand_segment" : "Upscale"
            }
          ],
          "real_estate_type_experience" : [
            {
              "real_estate" : "Government"
            }
          ],
          "property_type_experience" : [
            {
              "property_type" : "Full-Service Hotel"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "candidate",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "pNJLMHsBMf41SmWAkvYj",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "created_at" : "2021-07-15",
          "updated_at" : "2021-08-05T21:32:40.526078+00:00",
          "user_id" : 74776,
          "user_name" : "Steven-be8fa6",
          "first_name" : "Steven",
          "last_name" : "Li",
          "email" : "stevenli2b@mougulan.com",
          "contact_number" : "",
          "country_code" : "cn",
          "country" : "China",
          "city" : "Beijing",
          "state" : "Beijing",
          "address" : "Beijing, Beijing, China",
          "active_step" : 5,
          "is_active" : true,
          "is_deleted" : false,
          "is_csv_user" : true,
          "is_profile_completed" : true,
          "profile_completion_percentage" : 0.0,
          "gender" : "Female",
          "title_rank" : "Director of Sales & Marketing",
          "race_ethnicity" : "I do not wish to provide this information",
          "years_of_experience" : "3-6",
          "current_organizational_level" : "property",
          "base_salary" : 150,
          "bonus" : "",
          "benefits" : [
            {
              "benefit" : ""
            }
          ],
          "badge" : "",
          "languages" : [
            {
              "language" : "Chinese"
            }
          ],
          "geographies" : [
            {
              "geography" : "China"
            }
          ],
          "current_position" : "Asst. Director of Sales",
          "seeking_position" : [
            {
              "seeking_position" : "Regional Director of Sales"
            },
            {
              "seeking_position" : "Director of Sales & Marketing"
            },
            {
              "seeking_position" : "Director of Sales Strategy & Planning"
            }
          ],
          "current_location" : [
            {
              "city" : "Beijing",
              "country" : "China",
              "country_code" : "cn",
              "region" : "China"
            }
          ],
          "preferred_location" : [
            {
              "city" : "",
              "country" : "",
              "country_code" : "",
              "region" : ""
            }
          ],
          "compensation_seeking" : [
            {
              "compensation" : 150,
              "city" : "",
              "country" : "",
              "country_code" : "",
              "region" : ""
            }
          ],
          "brand_experience" : [
            {
              "brand" : "Shangri-La",
              "company" : "Other Lifestyle - Luxury"
            }
          ],
          "brand_segment_experience" : [
            {
              "brand_segment" : "Luxury"
            }
          ],
          "real_estate_type_experience" : [
            {
              "real_estate" : "Government"
            }
          ],
          "property_type_experience" : [
            {
              "property_type" : "Full-Service Hotel"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

Previously I was aggregating on nested compensation_seeking.compensation with term aggregation on title_rank.keyword as below

```
GET candidate/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "comp": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "title_rank.keyword", 
        "size": 50000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "level": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "compensation_seeking"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "level": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "compensation_seeking.compensation"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But now I desire to modify this aggregation on basis of seeking_position.seeking_position.keyword, that is instead of title rank I am looking for average compensation candidate is looking for based on his seeking_position.
I tried replacing title_rank.keyword with seeking_position.seeking_position.keyword but it returns empty bucket.

I also tried something like this but is of no help

```
GET candidate/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "comp": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "seeking_position"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "level": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "seeking_position.seeking_position.keyword"
          }
        },
        "aggs": {
          "level": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "compensation_seeking"
              },
            "aggs": {
              "level": {
                "avg": {
                  "field": "compensation_seeking.compensation"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "comp": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "seeking_position"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "seek_pos": {
          "terms": {
        "field": "seeking_position.seeking_position.keyword", 
        "exclude": "",
        "size": 50000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "level": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "compensation_seeking"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "level": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "compensation_seeking.compensation"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
        }
      }
      
    }
  }
}
```